# What are the options for stopping wetsuit booties becoming water logged?

Tags: gear, footwear, surfing, water-shoes

Whenever I surf with wetsuit booties on, either the boots themselves become waterlogged or the leg of the wetsuit fills with water. I've seen people use tape. Is this an effective method? What tape should I use? Do people have any other more effective methods?

Comment: We wear boots when diving warm water (not the same as we're submerged yes) but it's the water in the boot that helps keep your feet warm, once you get them off still in the water you really feel a cold difference.

Comment: They're called *wetsuit* booties for a reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tape is a useful way to do it, but you'll find it starts to tear up the neoprene fairly quickly.

My preferred solution when it is cold enough to require boots is to get the high ankle ones and tuck them into the wetsuit legs.this then means the water doesn't go into the boots.

In warmer weather suitable for a shortie wetsuit I just wouldn't wear boots.